# Mock Microsoft sign-in functionality

Tags: php, azure, docker, docker-compose

I use docker compose. Out application uses Microsoft sign in server. When I open my local web site, it redirects me to the `login.microsoftonline.com`. However local web site is located on localhost. And that sign in service says:

```
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:
```

Potentially I can generate right configs for localhost in the Azure AD B2C as it described in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/commerce/e-commerce-extensibility/mock-sign-in, but first of all I don't have access to the Azure AD B2C. And second, it would still require third party server->internet connection. I want to make local web site fully isolated and independent.
Is there some docker image that mocks the behavior of the login.microsoftonline.com and always returns positive response? Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you require is a mock server with OpenID Connect functionality which would replace Microsoft as Identity Provider.

You should take a look to [the image created by Soluto](https://github.com/Soluto/oidc-server-mock).

Include their defined service on your `docker-compose` and replace the Identity Provider URL on your local application from `login.microsoftonline.com` to `oidc-server-mock` (it will automatically create also the `.well-known` path according to all the OIDC requirements).